# How to manually set legend intervals in a "stat_contour" plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I want to manually set legend intervals in a "stat_contour" plot, and I have tried the following codes:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
volcano3d <- melt(volcano)
names(volcano3d) <- c("x", "y", "z")

v <- ggplot(volcano3d, aes(x, y, z = z)) + stat_contour(geom="polygon", aes(fill=..level..), bins=10) + scale_fill_gradientn(name="value", colors=c("green", "blue", "yellow"),breaks=c(100,150,200))
```

[image]

As the figure shows, the legend only contains 150, but I want to show numbers 100, 150, 200 in the legend. I wonder how to do this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `limits` argument to `scale_fill_gradientn`

```
ggplot(volcano3d, aes(x, y, z = z)) +
    stat_contour(geom="polygon", aes(fill=..level..), bins=10) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(
        name="value",
        colors=c("green", "blue", "yellow"),
        breaks=c(100,150,200),
        limits = c(100, 200))
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks a lot.